# Retrieving facets through DSpace REST API

Tags: rest, facet, dspace

Title says it all. I am trying to retrieve a list of facets I can filter on using the DSpace REST API. I have done some digging around and I can't seem to figure out how this is accomplished (if it can be accomplished)

Answer (score 1):

Facet information is not available in the DSpace 5/DSpace 6 REST service.

https://demo.dspace.org/rest/collections?expand=all

The DSpace 7 REST API is under development.  Since the DSpace 7 UI will be built on top of the REST API, the api will need to provide full support for browse options.

Here is a link to the DSpace 7 REST documentation: https://github.com/DSpace/Rest7Contract